# Building SQL statements using array entries

Tags: ruby

What is the proper way to build a string dynamically using items from an array. Currently I am building it using this;

```
@ar.each do |b|
    @str = @str + "select '#{b[0]}' as SourceGUID, '#{b[1]}' as SourceFileName, '#{b[2]}' as FullPath, #{b[3]} as SizeInMB, #{b[4]} as ItemCount, #{b[5]} as ParentCount, #{b[6]} as ChildCount, '#{b[7]}' as CaseName, #{b[8]} as ProcessedSizeMB\n union all\n"
end
```

This is obviously a horrible way to do it. Is there a way to achieve it using `.join`?

Comment: which ever way you do it, please avoid sql injection attack if you're planning on injecting from an array

Answer (score 0):

A draft

```
2.3.1 :028 > row = %w(my_id my_name my_age)
 => ["my_id", "my_name", "my_age"] 
2.3.1 :029 > aliases = %w(id name age)
 => ["id", "name", "age"] 
2.3.1 :030 > fields = row.zip aliases
 => [["my_id", "id"], ["my_name", "name"], ["my_age", "age"]] 
2.3.1 :031 > fields.map do |field|
2.3.1 :032 >   field[0] = "'#{field[0]}'"
2.3.1 :033?>   field.join(" AS ")
2.3.1 :034?> end.join(", ")
 => "'my_id' AS id, 'my_name' AS name, 'my_age' AS age"
```